# Since when are question votes different from answer votes?

Tags: discussion, voting

Just got this message:[image]  Have question votes always been treated differently than votes on answers?

Comment: Since today! (:

Comment: see: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90378/answers-questions-votes-cast-rules/90431#90431

Answer (score 3):

Ah, should've figured this would be on meta.SO.

[Separate vote pools for questions and answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89534/separate-vote-pools-for-questions-and-answers)

So now it's 30 votes per day for either questions or answers + 10 additional votes only for questions.

Comment: The answer is always on MSO, the difficulty is (usually) in finding it.

Comment: I've stopped visiting MSO because of all the irrelevant noise. This is why I believe that MSO should be for Stack Overflow only, and things that affect *all* sites should have their own Meta

Comment: @Mark I can only agree with you here. As the sites all get bigger, I don't think its doing either the SO users who regard that as *their* meta or the rest of us who have to remember to visit it for any meta meta discussion any favours.

Comment: I find meta.SO to be too hostile to outsiders, unless you're a regular you can't take part in the discussions.  The only good thing about it is that when something has been discussed and "decided" you can usually find a question about it or a duplicate question with a link to the earlier discussion.

Comment: For a while I thought it was just me but it looks like others are seeing MSO the same way I am. i.e. Not a nice place at all. There should really be a dedicated site for announcements that affect the entire network.

Comment: @John, unless you're already epic on SO or mSO, they're extremely hostile. Also, don't even *think* about addressing a problem that's outside the scope of SO, there are no other SE sites but SO to those on mSO. They've got a pretty extreme case of Programmer [Groupthink](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Groupthink) going on.

Comment: @chris too true. On Meta Stack Overflow, if its not a problem for stack overflow itself then it isn't a problem at all, as far as I can see. For example the utter indifference when us and SF complain about being bad question dumping grounds - MSO don't care (as a group effect anyway, there are of course decent individuals there), their toilet is flushing away the bad questions just fine!

Comment: @ward that's odd.. putting aside the "everything you can think of has been asked and discussed 6 times by now on meta.so" burnout factor, what examples would you give to support this.. anything from http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/130540/ward

Comment: @John Gardeniers: The dedicated site for announcements is the blog: http://blog.stackexchange.com. If that does not provide enough detail, there is a "Recent Feature Changes" list: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59445/recent-feature-changes-to-stack-exchange. Beyond that lies meta.Stackoverflow, which gets into the really nitty-gritty, insider-baseball stuff. Three resources to pick from, depending on your level of interest in this stuff.

Comment: @Robert: there's nothing on the blog about the voting changes, this is the first I've heard of the new features list (maybe there should be a link somewhere obvious?), and meta has problems as previously mentioned.

Comment: @Robert, I've been on SF for a year and 10 months, yet have never seen mention before of blog.stackexchange.com being the place where system wide announcements are made. The point of course is that this kind of information has been made anything but obvious. It's not mentioned in the FAQ and the site name certainly doesn't hint at it being an announcement site. In short, the information has effectively been hidden. Can this please be rectified?

Comment: @Robert Cartaino - I've favourited the MSO question you mention, which helps keep track of that but it doesn't alter the fact that this was effectively sprung on the majority of SF users by surprise. It doesn't alter the fact that its a (imho) *bad* idea, and it doesn't alter the fact that MSO is an unfriendly place for people from other SE sites which makes going there and trying to find info/get questions answered an incredible chore for those of us who don't 'live' at SO.

Comment: @Jeff: Aren't you somewhat involved in StackExchange?  I expect you to instantly recall everything that has ever happened on the entire network of sites, including the fact that most serverfault-related meta questions were migrated off meta.SO over to here: http://meta.serverfault.com/users/6177/ward

Comment: @Jeff some more: I haven't been too badly abused in my own questions, e.g. http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/285/whats-wrong-with-serverfault (but I still don't think it was really a duplicate) and http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/285/whats-wrong-with-serverfault  Before meta.SF existed, it was certainly almost impossible to get SF-ers to comment on questions, you'd ask a question and get lots of misinterpretations by SO-ers.

Comment: @Jeff even more: In one case I did feel set-upon and deleted my question.  Anyway, the best example of SO vs. SF was the attempt to ask SO-ers not to blindly migrate lousy questions to SF.  I think that's what most of us think of when we think of "how meta.SO thinks of SF."

Comment: @Ward your last example was certainly what I was thinking of when I said that the vibe on MSO is: "if something isn't a problem for SO users then it isn't a problem full stop". Usually with an added "now would you interlopers like a cookie and a sarcastic comment before you go back to your cute little websites?" to follow :-(